# How to filter 2D array in Flex and perform computation based on Filtering

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows:

```
Asia     India   Calcutta 100 200
Asia     India   Chennai  200 400
Asia     India   Mumbai   100 300
Asia     PAK     XXXXXX   100 300
Asia     PAK     SSSSSS   200 100
Americas Canada  Ottawa   200 200
Americas Canada  Toronto  120 200
Americas Mexico  Sonoro   110 500
```

I need to filter the above dataset also calculating the sum of each region by the use of a specific filter such as a region name is given.(eg. Asia)

Output for filter Asia must give me :

```
India   400 900
PAK     300 400
```

How is this possible in Flex array 2D.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a university project this one, by Flex array 2D are you meaning a Multi-dimensional associative array? if so this can be achieved by bucketing by the parameter names.                              var myArray:Array = [];                                               myArray["Asia"]["India"]["Calcutta"]["someProperty"] = 100

Comment: Filtering a dataset and calculating a sum are two different tasks.  You'll have to be more specific on your data structure.  Do you have an array of objects?  Or two associative arrays?  If it is truly a 2D array you'll have to do a lot of looping and have a complicated algorithm.

Comment: You are trying to do things that are normally handled by database engines. Database engines are specially designed for such kind of tasks and will perform them significantly faster than flex code.

Comment: @Reboog711 yes this is truly 2d array which i get from Excel.Any idea as to how to proceed ?

Comment: The number of numerical columns are dynamic,and the array is also dynamic.,cant predict the number of columns.But target is to drill the data based on particular filter (eg, a specific region India)